# Why the predicted value by LinearRegression is exactly the same as the true value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm doing a regression by `LinearRegression` and get the mean squared error 0. I think there should be some deviation(at least small). Could you please explain this phenomenon?

```
## Import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import urllib.request

## Import dataset
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Data-Science-FMI/ml-from-scratch-2019/master/data/house_prices_train.csv',
                           'house_prices_train.csv')
df_train = pd.read_csv('house_prices_train.csv')
x = df_train['GrLivArea'].values.reshape(1, -1)
y = df_train['SalePrice'].values.reshape(1, -1)
print('The explanatory variable is', x)
print('The variable to be predicted is', y)

## Regression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
mean_squared_error(y, reg.predict(x))
print('The MSE is', mean_squared_error(y, reg.predict(x)))
print('Predicted value is', reg.predict(x))
print('True value is', y)
```

The result is

```
The explanatory variable is [[1710 1262 1786 ... 2340 1078 1256]]
The variable to be predicted is [[208500 181500 223500 ... 266500 142125 147500]]
The MSE is 0.0
Predicted value is [[208500. 181500. 223500. ... 266500. 142125. 147500.]]
True value is [[208500 181500 223500 ... 266500 142125 147500]]
```

Comment: you never seem to split your data, so you are training and testing on the same sample set hence perfect results. Have you heard of `train_test_split` ?

Comment: textbook case of OVERFITTING. you need to split the data into training and test sets and then go on. now you fit the whole dataset into the model

Comment: Thank you @GhandiFloss and seralouk. I can not image that the overfitting in this case is such serious.

Comment: @LAD you are fitting on (x,y) and then predicting on x again, which you just used for training your model. This is overfitting. As the others suggested, you need to split your data into training and testing subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the comments are certainly correct that a model's score on its own training set will be inflated, it is unlikely to get a perfect fit with linear regression, especially with just one feature.

Your problem is that you've reshaped the data incorrectly: `reshape(1, -1)` makes an array of shape `(1, n)`, so your model thinks it has `n` features and `n` outputs with only a single sample, and so is a multiple linear regression with a perfect fit.  Try instead with `reshape(-1, 1)` for `x` and no reshaping for `y`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very subtle.

Comment: This is a good point. Perfect fit only possible on a straight line, still only to a floating precision